# JavaScript: Add time zone offset to AM/PM date saved as a string?

Tags: javascript, date, time, date-conversion

I have the multiple strings in the format (GMT -7):

```
var date1 = "08-12-2014 10:38 PM"; //MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM
```

I want to change the date/time to GMT -3 (essentially add 4 hours to each date/time). I can't pull the dates in UTC, they are all in the above format. What is the best way to this without messing up the date and keeping the AM/PM format?

Comment: Is that supposed to be 2014 December 8 or 2014 August 12?

Comment: Use moment.js It is a nice little libraray that takes away all the complexity of date manipulation. (http://momentjs.com/). Ideally the dates should be dealt with in UTC format but you may or may not have control over that (depending on where you get your dates from).

Comment: as @Magrangs mentioned, use momentjs. There you can define timezone, parse the string and then change the timezone to get new date & time.

Comment: I am unable to pull the dates in UTC, they are in the format of MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM

Answer (score 0):

JS has a built in timezone method,

```
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
```

will return the minuets offset from UTC time.   Divide it by 60 to get hours,

```
var x = n/60;
```

and then use the setHours() method on `d` to add/subtract `x` to/from the timestamp.

```
var mydatetouse = d.setHours(x);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sethours.asp

Answer (score 0):

Using moment.js I have figured out the answer to my question:

```
var date1 = "08-12-2014 10:38 PM"; //MM-DD-YYYY HH:MM
var new date = moment(date1, "MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A").add(4, 'hours').format("MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm A"));
```